# Prediction intervals exponential smoothing statsmodels

Tags: time-series, prediction-interval, exponential-smoothing

I've been reading through [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/). I am working through the exponential smoothing section attempting to model my own data with python instead of R. I am confused about how to get prediction intervals for forecasts using [ExponentialSmoothing](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html) in statsmodels. Is this something I have to build a custom state space model using [MLEModel](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel) for? This is as far as I've gotten.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
ses_seas_trend = ExponentialSmoothing(train.Volume,
                                  trend='add',
                                  damped=True,
                                  seasonal='add', 
                                  seasonal_periods=12)

ses_st_model = ses_seas_trend.fit()
yhat = ses_st_model.predict(start='2018-07', end='2020-02')
```

Comment: I believe I found the answer to part of my question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43508/208879.

If I'm able to figure out the state space model piece in statsmodels I will update. If anyone has any advice on that piece it would be appreciated.

Comment: I just posted a similar question on stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736632/how-to-obtain-prediction-intervals-with-statsmodels-timeseries-models

Comment: My question is actually related to time series as well. I'm pretty sure we need to use the MLEModel api I referenced above. According to this [example](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_local_linear_trend.html), we can get prediction intervals for any model that can be broken down into state space form. The book I referenced above goes over the details in the exponential smoothing chapter. I ended up just using R to get my prediction intervals instead of python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statsmodels will now calculate the prediction intervals for [exponential smoothing models](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.exponential_smoothing.ExponentialSmoothing.html). As of now, direct prediction intervals are only available for additive models. Multiplicative models can still be calculated via the regular [ExponentialSmoothing](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html) class. Prediction intervals for multiplicative models can still be calculated via [statespace](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/statespace.html), but this is much more difficult as the state space form must be specified manually. Here are some [additional notes](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/statespace.html#linear-exponential-smoothing-models) on the differences between the exponential smoothing options.